# Performance issue with dc.js with graphs in multiple tabs on a page

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Having an odd performance issue where I have one set of data and have multiple tabs which create different crossfilters from the data.

I noticed that if you switch tabs, the graphs slows down. I have tried to 'destroy' the crossfilters between tabs with the following (I store all the crossfilters in one object.

```
deleteAllCharts: function (){
            d3.selectAll(".dashboard_chart").selectAll("svg").remove();
            Object.keys(crossStore).forEach(function (keyid){
                dc.filterAll();
                crossStore[keyid].remove();
            });
        }
```

Would it be worth setting the filters to null?

Also I currently don't do the same for dimensions/groups. Would it be worth destroying these?

Comment: Different Crossfilter objects shouldn't really interfere with each other. Can you put together an example that shows the problem so we can get a better handle on what is happening?

Comment: What I noticed was that to create a crossfilter from another crossfilter, the best thing is to have your reduce function store the set of data objects you want in the next crossfilter as an array and then concat those to create a data array from which to create the next crossfilter. This resolved the lag.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just repeat what I said above:
What I noticed was that to create a crossfilter from another crossfilter, the best thing is to have your reduce function store the set of data objects you want in the next crossfilter create a data array from which to create the next crossfilter. This resolved the lag.

So this:
        foodProbingCookedGroup = foodIdDimension.group().reduce(
            // callback for when items are added to the results.
            function (p,v){
                if (p.firstProbeTime == null){
                    p.firstProbeTime = v.dd;
                    p.lastProbeTime = v.dd;
                    p.probed_food_name = v.probed_food_name;
                }
                p.finalProbeTime = v.dd;
                p.lifeInMinutes = (v.dd.getTime() - p.firstProbeTime.getTime()) / 60000;

```
            p.stationLife.push({
                staff_name : v.staff_name, 
                probed_food_name: v.probed_food_name,
                minutesAtPreviousStation : (v.dd.getTime()-p.firstProbeTime.getTime()) / 60000,
                previous_station_name : p.previous_station_name,
                currentProbeTime : v.dd,
                temperature : v.probed_food_history_temperature,
                station_name : v.station_name,
                station_type : v.station_type 
            });
            p.previous_station_name = v.station_name;
            return p;
        },
        // Callback for when deleted
        function (p,v){
            // Do nothing.
            return p;
        },
        // Initialise function
        function (){
            return ({
                firstProbeTime: null,
                lastProbeTime: null,
                finalProbeTime: null,
                lifeInMinutes: 0,
                probed_food_name: "",
                previous_station_name: "",
                stationLife: [] 
            });
        }
    );
```

Then on the range chart you add this:

```
        .on("postRedraw", function (chart) {renderFoodTimeChards(chart);});
```

Then the function does the following:
    function renderFoodTimeChards (filterChart) {

```
    var data = [];

    var foodGroup;
    //Get the range of the filtered data.
    if (typeof filterChart == 'undefined' || filterChart.filter() === null ){
        foodGroup = foodProbingCookedGroup.top(Infinity);
    }
    else{
        var fromDate = filterChart.filter()[0].getTime();
        var toDate = filterChart.filter()[1].getTime();
        foodGroup = foodProbingCookedGroup.top(Infinity).filter(function(d){
            var timeToCheck = d.value.firstProbeTime.getTime();
            return ( timeToCheck >= fromDate && timeToCheck <= toDate)
        });

    }
    // Derive the set of data we need. 
    foodGroup.forEach(function (d){
        data = data.push({
            probed_food_name: d.value.probed_food_name,
            lifeInMinutes : d.value.lifeInMinutes
        });
    })

    crossStore["foodLifeStore"] = crossfilter(data);
```